# Unable to stop a disabled checkbox from being affected by a hover event in the CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two sets of checkboxes, which act as a star rating system. One of the star ratings is disabled (by using the `disabled` attribute on the checkboxes), while the other one isnt.

When the user hovers over stars in the star rating system, they change colour to yellow. However if the star rating system is disabled, I do not want them to change colour when covered. I have tried to do this by using `:not([disabled])` in the checkbox hover event in the CSS, but the stars still change colour on hover.

```css
.rating,
.rating label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating .half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked):not([disabled]) label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked) label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating input:checked~label:hover,
.rating label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p>This star rating system should not change colour on hover as the checkboxes are disabled</p>

<fieldset class="rating" id="93">
  <input type="checkbox" id="5star_1" name="rating" value="5" disabled/>
  <label class="full" for="5star_1" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="4halfstar_1" name="rating" value="4.5" disabled/>
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar_1" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="4star_1" name="rating" value="4" disabled/>
  <label class="full" for="4star_1" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="3halfstar_1" name="rating" value="3.5" disabled/>
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar_1" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="3star_1" name="rating" value="3" disabled/>
  <label class="full" for="3star_1" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="2halfstar_1" name="rating" value="2.5" disabled/>
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar_1" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="2star_1" name="rating" value="2" disabled/>
  <label class="full" for="2star_1" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="1halfstar_1" name="rating" value="1.5" disabled/>
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar_1" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="1star_1" name="rating" value="1" disabled/>
  <label class="full" for="1star_1" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="halfstar_1" name="rating" value="0.5" disabled/>
  <label class="half" for="halfstar_1" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>

<br><br>

<p>This one does what it is supposed to (change its colour on hover)</p>

<fieldset class="rating" id="23">
  <input type="checkbox" id="5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="5star" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>
```

Here is what it looks like in the developer tools with the hover state being forced on:

[image]

Comment: I have rolled back your work because the question should contain the problem, ***NOT*** the fixed solution.

Comment: I tested it out on the code snippet and your update appeared to work correctly. It's best to test it in situ on your project, but I admit the code sippets here can be tempting .... `:-)`

Comment: You have a code issue : one of your inputs in the first list is not disabled.

Comment: @Martin Thank you, fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking CSS to check if the *container* class has the disabled attribute (or not). You need to ask it if the `input` within the class has this attribute

something like:

```
.rating input:checked~label,
.rating input:not(:checked):not(:disabled) + label:hover,
.rating input:not(:checked):not(:disabled) + label:hover~label {
    color: #FFD700;
}
```

Note:
You may do well to remove the first and third rules as well, and simply have the second rule apply.

## Snippet:

```css
.rating,
.rating label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating .half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating input:checked~label,
.rating input:not(:checked):not(:disabled) + label:hover,
.rating input:not(:checked):not(:disabled) + label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


.rating input:checked~label:hover,
.rating label:hover~input:checked~label,
.rating input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p>This star rating system should not change colour on hover as the checkboxes are disabled</p>

<fieldset class="rating" id="93">
  <input type="checkbox" id="5star_1" name="rating" value="5" disabled/>
  <label class="full" for="5star_1" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="4halfstar_1" name="rating" value="4.5" disabled/>
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar_1" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="4star_1" name="rating" value="4" disabled/>
  <label class="full" for="4star_1" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="3halfstar_1" name="rating" value="3.5" disabled/>
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar_1" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="3star_1" name="rating" value="3" disabled/>
  <label class="full" for="3star_1" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="2halfstar_1" name="rating" value="2.5" disabled/>
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar_1" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="2star_1" name="rating" value="2" disabled/>
  <label class="full" for="2star_1" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="1halfstar_1" name="rating" value="1.5" disabled/>
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar_1" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="1star_1" name="rating" value="1" disabled/>
  <label class="full" for="1star_1" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="halfstar_1" name="rating" value="0.5" disabled/>
  <label class="half" for="halfstar_1" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>

<br><br>

<p>This one does what it is supposed to (change its colour on hover)</p>

<fieldset class="rating" id="23">
  <input type="checkbox" id="5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="5star" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>
```